# Specify default notification style in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification, info.plist

New in Mountain Lion, Cocoa apps include support for the `NSUserNotificationAlertStyle` key in Info.plist, which allows the developer to specify a default style for their notifications.

Obviously, the user can change this, but it makes sense to allow the developer to provide a sensible default.

Does any parallels to that exist in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the user can change the default alert style, which is found in the Settings > Notifications > [APP]